# UWP. The name of the app that will appear in the Microsoft Store

Tags: deployment, uwp, store, appxmanifest

I need to set the name of the app that will appear in the Microsoft Store. Which **element** or **attribute** should I define in package.appxmanifest?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest">
  <Identity Name="" 
            Version="" 
            Publisher="" />
  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>The Name of the app in the Store</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName></PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo></Logo>
  </Properties>
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="" StartPage="">
      <VisualElements DisplayName="The Name of the app in the Store" Description=""
           Logo="" SmallLogo=""  
           ForegroundText="" BackgroundColor="">
         <SplashScreen Image="" />
      </VisualElements>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
</Package>
```

Is it **Properties -> DisplayName** element or **Applications -> Application -> VisualElements -> DisplayName attribute** ?

Because on [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/schema-root) in the description of the package.appxmanifest is wrote, that the first one and the second one are like the friendly names for users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name on the store is the **Properties -> DisplayName**, the Application -> VisualElements -> DisplayName is actually the app name which appears on title bar of your uwp app and also in the start menu.

Associating your project with the reserved app name on the **dev center** automatically fills the name for you.

**Reserve app name** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/create-your-app-by-reserving-a-name
**Associating app with store**

> Rightclick project -> Store -> Associate app with store -> pick one of your already reserved app names or reserve a new one.

Comment: Also remember to reserve your name in the Store and then you can associate it with the project in VS.